# Golang Gorilla Session not working in Chrome Browser But works on Safari and Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, session, web, go, browser

I am having trouble deploying my golang web app into a live server.

While running this code locally, it was working perfectly fine.

Note that I did the following checks to try to solve this problem:

1. I made sure that my systemd had the environment variable SESSION_KEY.
   ( Printed out the os.Getenv("SESSION_KEY") and it returned the key.
2. I tried to check all the returned errors from the below functions.
   ( All of the errors are nil; however when I try to get_session after the fact, it returns false for the ok variable and 0 for the uid)
3. I tried working this code on firefox, safari, and chrome. ( Chrome is the only one that does not work. )

I only pulled out the code that had to do with "github.com/gorilla/sessions" package.

```js
var store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte(os.Getenv("SESSION_KEY")))


func init() {

 fmt.Println(store)
 fmt.Println("SESSION KEY BELOW: ", os.Getenv("SESSION_KEY"))

 store.Options = &sessions.Options{
     Domain:   "buckler.solutions",
     Path:     "/",
     MaxAge:   3600 * 8, // 8 hours
     HttpOnly: true,
 }
}

func get_session(request *http.Request) (int, error) {
 // META: Gets the session cookie and returns the result.

 session, err := store.Get(request, "session-name")
 fmt.Println("ERROR FROM store.Get: ", err)
 untyped_uid, untyped_ok := session.Values["uid"]
 fmt.Println("SESSIONUID before cast: ", untyped_uid)
 uid, ok := untyped_uid.(int)
 fmt.Println("SESSIONUID after cast: ", uid)

 if !untyped_ok || !ok {
  fmt.Println("GET SESSION ERRORS.")
  fmt.Println("UNTYPED_OK: ", untyped_ok)
  fmt.Println("OK: ", ok)
  return -1, errors.New("no session")
 } else {
  return uid, nil
 }
}

func set_session(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request, uid int) {
 // META: Sets the session cookie and saves it.

 session, err := store.Get(request, "session-name")
 fmt.Println("SESSION in SET SESSION: ", session)
 fmt.Println("SESSION SET ERROR:", err)

 session.Values["uid"] = uid
 fmt.Println("UID: ", uid)

 err = session.Save(request, response)
 fmt.Println("SESSION SAVE ERROR:", err)
 
}

func clear_session(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
 // META: Clears the session so that it won't remember the user.

 session, err := store.Get(request, "session-name")
 fmt.Println("ERROR CLEARING SESSION: ", err)
 session.Values["uid"] = -1
 session.Save(request, response)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think some proper error handling would help you quickly debug your problem and see just exactly what may be the problem.

In Golang its standard practice to handle the error right after its declared.
Example: in your get_session method

```
session, err := store.Get(request, "session-name")
if err != nil {
   return -1, err
}
```

The problem in your code is that you arent stopping execution if an error occurs which makes it 10x harder to figure out where something might've went wrong.

Sometimes its even helpful (for debugging) to add small comments that will help you even pinpoint the error more, like:

```
session, err := store.Get(request, "session-name")
if err != nil {
   fmt.Println("hey an error occurred trying to get the session: ",err.Error())
   return -1, err
}
```

I think once you put in some proper error handling you can debug your issue quickly. (And handle every error, dont ignore any)